# Sketch Symbols - maintaining padding between 2 paragraphs when adding/ removing text

Tags: sketch-app, responsive-design

I wish to create the following responsive symbol for a popup in Sketch.

[image: pop-up default]

I am a big fan of the Resizing functionality built in to sketch, however cannot solve the following problem with the Resizing tools.

If I duplicate the text "Curabitur lobortis id lore...", not all the text is shown, as there is not enough space in the default placeholder. I have to manually increase the height of the symbol, which also writes over the 2nd block of text.

[image]

My question is, what can I add to make the top level text block automatically expand to fit its contents, whilst maintaining the padding to the 2nd text block of text located beneath it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to download a plugin to get the job done. Luckily, the two that solve your problem are free.

---

## Paddy

Automate padding and spacing for your Sketch layers. **[View on Github](https://github.com/dwilliames/paddy-sketch-plugin)**

[image: Paddy spacing]

---

## Anima

Anima has a lot of different functionality built into their one plugin. The one that applies is Auto Layout and the idea of Stacks.

**[Read on Medium](https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/auto-layout-introducing-stacks-flexbox-for-sketch-c8a11422c7b5)** | **[Homepage](https://www.animaapp.com/)**

[image: Anima Stacks in action]